# Difference between Messages and Active Messages in Azure Service bus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am trying to create a chart for Count of messages in Azure Service Bus, I see there are two options

```
i . Count of Messages in Queue/Topic
ii. Count of Active messages in Queue/Topic
```

What is the difference between these two ?

Answer (score 5):

Message count - total messages in the queue with various statuses (scheduled, deferred, dead-lettered, in transfer, transfer dead-lettered).
Active messages - messages available for receiving and processing.

For example, let's say there's a message that is available for processing, one message scheduled in the future (not available for receiving and processing), and one message dead-lettered. The message count will show 3. Active message count will only show 1.

Comment: Thank you  @Sean Feldman, Also just wanted to know more about "Active Connections", "Connections Opened" and "Connections Closed" , could you please refer me to a good documentation link if available .

Comment: That's a different question which I believe is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62420007/azure-service-bus-active-connections-connections-opened-and-connections-cl). I will answer it there. Piling up questions for unrelated or new questions tends to hide the information others would be looking for.

Comment: What is the difference between scheduled and active? Why would a message be in the queue but not available for receiving and processing?

Comment: Scheduling messages allows enqueuing w/o the worry those will be processed prematurely. A `scheduled at` property ensures scheduled messages are not visible until the time is right. Active messages are immediately available for consumption the moment they are added.