# Azure service Bus "Active Connections", "Connections Opened" and "Connections Closed"

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am trying to find more information about "Active Connections", "Connections Opened" and "Connections Closed" in Azure Service Bus Metrics.

Can someone help me finding a good document to understand these "Active Connections", "Connections Opened" and "Connections Closed" in Azure Service Bus ?

Answer (score -1):

- Active Connections - the number of active connections on a namespace as well as on an entity.
- Connections Opened - The number of open connections.
- Connections Closed - The number of closed connections.

Source: [Azure Service Bus metrics in Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-metrics-azure-monitor#connection-metrics)

Azure Service Bus work by establishing a connection between the broker and the client. The connection is maintained until it is lost or disconnect is initiated. The importance of this metric to show certain patterns of the application or system using the Azure Service Bus. For example, an excessive number of connections established could indicate of a problem in managing the connections. It's important to remember that a namespace has a quota on the number of connections that can be established (5,000).

Comment: So what's the difference between an active connection and an open connection?